# Android retrofit demo listview not showing all repos

Tags: android

I'm following a retrofit tutorial https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

The app compiles and runs but doesn't allow you to scroll beyond the first page. Any idea what I'm missing? Does this tutorial even have you show all the repos?

[image]

https://github.com/morenoh149/HarryLearnsAndroid/tree/master/HttpDemo

```
package com.harrymoreno.httpdemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import com.harrymoreno.httpdemo.GitHubRepoAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pagination_list);

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        GithubClient client = retrofit.create(GithubClient.class);
        Call<List<GithubRepo>> call = client.reposForUser("morenoh149");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GithubRepo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Response<List<GithubRepo>> response) {
                List<GithubRepo> repos = response.body();

                listView.setAdapter(new GitHubRepoAdapter(MainActivity.this, repos));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/pagination_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I ran the author's example and put my GitHub handle in https://github.com/futurestudio/android-retrofit-video the example does not query for all the repos so I followed the tutorial correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use scrollview then listview in xml file